# Test event handler with full rendered DOM Leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, leaflet, enzyme

I have a component called 'Map' responsible for manage everything I need to render a map using Leaflet plugin (only create the container for the map, request the leaflet map to render and request the markers to render), and it works great.

**My Map component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mapId = `map-${uniqueID()}`;
    this._map = null;
    this.state = {
      markers: []
    };
    //some more code
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // ...create map using Leaflet plugin inside $(".my-component > .map")
    // ...render markers
  }

  addZoomEndHandler(handler) {
    this._map.on('zoomend', handler);
  }

  addEventHandlers = (markers) => {
    markers.forEach((m) => {
      const marker = m;
      marker.eventHandlers = {
        click(e) {
          marker.onClick && marker.onClick(e);
        }
        //some other events
      };
    });
  }

  //some more code

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="my-component map-container">
        <div id={this.mapId} className="map">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write some tests using Enzyme and Jest but I'm facing some problems.

**Here is one of my failing tests:**

```
it('should trigger the marker click event', (done) => {
  const onMarkerClickMock = jest.fn(),
    myMarkers = [{
                  id: '0',
                  geolocation: { coordinates: [38.734577, -9.21739], type: 'Point' },
                  onClick: onMarkerClickMock
                }],
    markerSelector = '#path__0';


  $.ajax.mockImplementationOnce((request) => {
    expect(request.url).toContain(`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.&key=${myKey}`);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      fs.readFile(`${__dirname}test-data/google.js`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        request.success(resolve(data));
      });
    });
  });

  const map = mount(<Map markers={myMarkers} />);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const markers = map.state('markers');
    expect(markers).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(typeof markers[0].onClick).toBe('function');
    expect(markers[0].onClick).toEqual(onMarkerClickMock);
    map.find(markerSelector).simulate('click');         // <- failing here
    expect(onMarkerClickMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    done();
  }, 500);
});
```

First I had problems with `setTimeOut` and then figured out I needed to call `done()` inside it. Now when `map.find(markerSelector)` is called it is failing with this error message:

> *Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.*

I did `map.html()` and it returned only this:

```
<div class="my-component map-container" role="button" tabindex="0">
    <div id="map-61bb504b-8c6d-fb91-e743-e67f4b6b3f8a" class="map"></div>
</div>
```

But I expected it returned something like this with leaflet map rendered:

```
<div class="my-component map-container" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <div id="map-61bb504b-8c6d-fb91-e743-e67f4b6b3f8a" class="map leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag" tabindex="0" style="position: relative; outline: none;">
      <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(-319px, 0px, 0px);">
         <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
            <div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;">
               <div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);">
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(268px, -73px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124766!3i98632!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229400!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=99746" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(524px, -73px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124767!3i98632!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229832!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=94189" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(268px, 183px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124766!3i98633!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515227686!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=14690" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(524px, 183px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124767!3i98633!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229832!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=98859" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(12px, -73px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124765!3i98632!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229400!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=40319" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(780px, -73px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124768!3i98632!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229832!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=22545" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(12px, 183px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124765!3i98633!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515227686!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=86334" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(780px, 183px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124768!3i98633!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229832!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=27215" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-244px, -73px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124764!3i98632!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515218768!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=61271" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(1036px, -73px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124769!3i98632!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229832!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=81972" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-244px, 183px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124764!3i98633!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515216758!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=41588" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
                  <div class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" data-pending="0" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(1036px, 183px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img draggable="false" alt="" role="presentation" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m5!1m4!1i18!2i124769!3i98633!4i256!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i515229832!3m12!2spt!3sUS!5e18!12m4!1e68!2m2!1sset!2sRoadmap!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0&amp;key=AIzaSyCwHM3UZdSmdNOW2WvFH8UuG4YtgKCv000&amp;token=86642" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; position: absolute; visibility: visible;"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane">
            <svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="704" height="480" viewBox="260 -40 704 480" style="transform: translate3d(260px, -40px, 0px);">
               <g>
                  <path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#e8008b" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#e8008b" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M613,200L600.3538070924236,134.9409774905928A 66.27671238780022,66,0,0,1,654.709286557388,148.49332062917586 z" id="path__0" type="" networkelement="0"></path>
               </g>
            </svg>
         </div>
         <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(3.19404e+07px, 2.52501e+07px, 0px) scale(131072);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="leaflet-control-container">
         <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
         <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
            <div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in leaflet-disabled" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div>
            <div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Map © 2020 <a target="_blank" href="https://developers.google.com/maps/">Google</a></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Why `mount()` don't fully render my component? What I'm missing here? Can anyone help me, please? I just want to confirm that my `onClick()` marker function is called...

Comment: The question lacks necessary details. What exactly is <Map>? Is it https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet ? This is integration test that doesn't make much sense. It isn't supposed to work like a real thing in Jest - and it doesn't. Enzyme is for testing React components, while React-Leaflet relies on Leaflet which is client-side vanilla JS that very likely requires real DOM and not fake JSDOM that Jest offers. I'd suggest to stick to testing your own code and not third-party lib.

Comment: @EstusFlask like I said Map component is"responsible for manage everything I need to render a map using Leaflet plugin". I'm using Leaflet plugin, not React-Leaflet plugin. And I'm using Leaflet because I need to use other plugins over this, like leaflet-semicircle plugin. My Map component only create the container for the map, request the leaflet map to render and request the markers  to render. I accept your explanation about DOM, JSDOM, Leaflet and Jest relationship. But I'm trying to test only my code. So how can I trigger that click to check if my `onMarkerClickMock` is called or not?

Comment: Is Map first-party component? Then test only the code you wrote and stub everything related to Leaflet. There's no guarantee that Leaflet will work as expected in Jest because it runs in Node with fake DOM. If you need to test the whole thing, better save this for e2e tests in real browser.